# RegEx to match specific javaDoc attribute in a CSS file, and extract data about the css defintion

Tags: php, css, regex, javadoc

I'm trying to store some meta data about CSS styles, which our app can use to build menus that allow the user to select those styles (amongst other things).

I thought the JavaDoc style comment was the best approach, and use an attribute like `config` or similar.  Then store a JSON style definition as the value of that property.

I've been trying to write some RegEx (PHP) to do the following:

1. Find all JavaDoc comments with `@config` attribute.
2. Extract the value of `@config` as the JSON object
3. Then match the following css TAG and CLASS names if they are defined under it.

So this comment and class definition could be extracted into 3 matches.

```
/**
 * @config {name:'Orange Title', order:1}
 */
h1.title_orange {

}
```

- **Match 1** : `{name:'Orange Title', order:1}`
- **Match 2** : `h1`
- **Match 3** : `title_orange`

What makes it more complex is the JSON part could be multiline, and the multilines may or may not contain the `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest task is on the assumptions you make (which things to test):

```
 (?:^\/\*\*[\s\n\r]+\*\s@config\s(.*)$|^\s+\*\/[\s\n\r]+[\#\.]?([\w-]+)\s*(?:[\#\.]*([\w-]+)\s*)*{$)
```

You can test it in this [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/IAtwXROiRG).

I assumed that you have config in the first comment line of the javaDoc, I also assumed that you may have multiple spaces randomly between these, that your words/classes/ids may have `-`.

What more do you need?

### EDIT

> This works great in Rubular. Although regex should be the same across languages, this doesn't seem to work in [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b9W) –  [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430657/alexander) 4 mins ago

You're right, so I compacted it into one match group and [this one seems to be working](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/b9X) (you have to click *preg_match_all* tab):

```
\/[*]{2}[\s\n\r]+\*\s@config\s(.*)[\s\n\r]+.*[\s\n\r]+\*\/[\s\n\r]+[\#\.]?([\w-]+)\s*(?:[\#\.]*([\w-]+)\s*)*{
```

Which means, I am considering the javaDoc and the CSS together (javaDoc with several lines). Still, there may be adjustments that need to be made.

### EDIT2

> Thats amazing, thanks so much! What if the @config wasn't always the first entry in the comment? Is that still possible ? –  [Matt Bryson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124981/matt-bryson) 7 mins ago

It is:

```
\/[*]{2}(?:[\s\n\r]+.*)*[\s\n\r]+\*\s@config\s(.*)[\s\n\r]+.*[\s\n\r]+\*\/[\s\n\r]+[\#\.]?([\w-]+)\s*(?:[\#\.]*([\w-]+)\s*)*{
```

You can try this one [**PHP Live Regex** in *preg_match_all* tab](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ba7).

### EDIT3

Matt evolved his own regex to [something simpler](https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/3). The problem seems that the capture groups cannot be repeated indefinitely with this (to get all CSS classes/ids):

```
(?:[\#\.\,]([\w-]+)\s*)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/6

Therefore, this still needs to be solved...

Comment: Great work! Sorry for removing my comment. I removed it because your original regex worked on the _preg_split_ tab. But this new regex is even better!

Comment: I think the beginning part, `\/\*\*`, can be replaced with `/[*]{2}` to make the regex a little simpler.

Comment: Thats amazing, thanks so much!    What if the @config wasn't always the first entry in the comment?  Is that still possible ?

Comment: @Armfoot Thanks so much for the help on this, life saver!   Iv'e attempted to modify you example, so we can allow more freedom around the comment structure, and Im getting very close..  https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/3  but the last part is confusing me.  How do we allow it to support multiple comma delimited declarations (see the example link) https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/3

Comment: Thinking about it, I might just match the whole CSS declaration (the tag/id/class part) and then process that afterwards to see how may there were, if it was a class, id or tag etc.  Makes the reg ex simpler, and Ill need to check the types anyway....

Comment: @MattBryson I have [tried a few ways](https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/6) with non-capture groups `(?:` but to no avail... I believe the problem is that capture groups cannot be repeated in the way we're trying to do. So you may have to do exactly that, capture the whole thing and break it apart in the code. Sorry about this, if someone can overcome this, feel also free to uncheck my answer :)

Comment: ok, @Armfoot i've 99% got it. The last bit that would be good, is if there is more than one config entry, id like to match all of them, any ideas?    The last example on here has the one that isn't matching...  https://regex101.com/r/jM0yH0/7

Comment: @MattBryson the problem is the same one: we're trying to repeat non-capturing groups with capture groups inside `(?:some(thing))*` and regex doesn't like it... [regular-expressions.info gives some hints about this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), but now I'm out of ideas...